# Почему не отправляется форма через ajax, не передается изображение?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Суть вопроса такова через форму не передается изображение , текст передается

```
<form id="myform"  action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">   
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do">
  
<input type="text"  name="text"/>

    <input type="file" name="file"  />

<input type="submit" id="btncontcall" value=" Ok "/>        

  </form>

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#btncontcall').click(function(){ 
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"bot_send.php", // Адрес обработчика
             data:$('#myform').serialize(),
             error:function(){$("#erconts").html("<span class='erconts'>Ошибка!</span>");},
            beforeSend: function() {
                 $("#erconts").html("<span class='erconts'>Отправляем...</span>");
             },
            success: function(result){
      $('#myform')[0].reset();
                $('#erconts').html(result);
                checkThis();
            }
         });
         return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: `$('#myform').serialize()` - оно это не делает, используйте `FormData`

Comment: почемуто не отправляет

Answer (score 0):

Так сработало

```
    (function ($) {
$("#myform").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/bot_send.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData($('#' + $(this).attr('id'))[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
                 error:function(){$("#erconts").html("<b style='color: red;'>Сталася помилка!</b>");},
                beforeSend: function() {
                     $("#erconts").html("<b>Відправляєм дані...</b>");
                 }, 
                success: function(result){
                    $('#myform')[0].reset();
                    $('#erconts').html(result);
                    checkThis();
                },
      });

});
  
}(jQuery));

       $("#answer").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#btncontcall").click();
       } });
```

Comment: `new FormData(this),`